# Spring Caching (concurrentmapcachemanager and ehcache) returns Old data sometimes

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ehcache, spring-cache

I'm using Spring caching (tried both JDK based concurrentmapcachemanager and Ehcache).

I face an issue while hitting the Spring annotated Cacheable method. 
That Cacheable method when hit, goes to DB and loads same data into Cache and returns me the same. 
Now I have written a method which refreshes/reloads the cache with new data from DB (which is my requirement). Say, if I hit that reloadCache method now I should ideally get new updated data. So I get that new updated data now. But if some other User logs-in and hits the same method he/she does not the data the first time. He/She when clears the cache from browser and does a re-login he/she gets that reloaded new data.

My server configuration is like :

1. I hit my application URL
2. Request goes to Web server
   (load-balanced 2 web servers)
3. Request then proceeds ahead to App
   server (again load-balanced 2 App servers)

I'll soon post my sample code for your reference, meanwhile request you to suggest any inputs based on the information that I provided.

Thank you,
Dev Study

Comment: are you using @CacheEvict in those refresh/reload cache methods? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358664/how-can-i-evict-all-cache-in-spring-boot)?

Comment: Yes JTejedor. I'm using @CacheEvict annotation to clear the filled cache.

Comment: Could it be because the use of different app servers? I.e. the first user hits over an app server and other user hits over a different app server, I think ehcache is proccess exclusive so... You need to evict the data in all server. Could it be?

Comment: `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` will keep updated/new cached data only on one instance. Therefore if you have 2 instances behind your load balancer, users might hit the instance with the obsolete data.

Comment: Actually I missed a point. I've disabled the second app server. Even then also it does not work. I check the logs and I confirm that the appropriate Evict and reload methods are executed indeed. Then also it returns stale data but I'm not sure on which condition I get that old data and that too for first login of some user @JTejedor

Comment: Yes, you're true. ConcurrentMapCacheManager isn't a distributed one. So to reload/refresh data on both app servers I run a script which reloads both App servers for which I get appropriate loggers. And even then also it does not work @Igor

Comment: Missing some critical information here: how is the cache key computed? Both for the caching AND evict sides. Can you add more code snippets showing your setup?

Comment: I investigated again with different scenarios. In my case, I use JBoss server (domain mode). So one instance of JBoss server on a single App server has got 2 sub servers (server-one, server-two) which run on 2 different ports like 8081, 8082. So if I directly hit my service on 8081 or 8082 (bypassing the web server) I see that data refreshes on one sub server and not on other. Also if I run Spring Ehcache on JBoss Standlone mode on my Local it works perfectly fine. So I want to know if there is any special configuration for this scenario. Please let me know if I'm going the right way.

Comment: I've not used any CacheKey generation algorithm from Spring cache. I am just doing a basic example for now. Will show some code snippet in sometime. @Louis Jacomet

Comment: Dear Friends, I found the same question that I have from another Stackoverflow article. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394427/ehcache-on-jboss-replication-in-one-split-server

This exactly is also my kind of environment. Please help if you're aware of this kind of configuration. @JTejedor